# Move div scroll from right to left side of the scroll area

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm looking for a solution of changing the location of a scroll for a div:
http://neutrinoteam.com/clients/sezer-tech.com/?page_id=32

I want to move the scroll to be to the left of the items instead of the right side.
Is there a solution for that ?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to position vertical scroll bar in html?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4152230/how-to-position-vertical-scroll-bar-in-html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try 'direction: rtl;' in the div css.
but it will also affect the inner text, so put all the content in a wrapper div, and for the wrapper, change the direction back to ltr.
Html:

```
<div id="Container">
    <div id="Content">
        bla bla
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#Container
{
    direction: rtl;
}
#Content
{
    direction: ltr;
}
```

or combined

```
<div style="direction: rtl;">
    <div style="direction: ltr;">
        bla bla
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

direction: rtl should work, but in this case whole text inside element and it's child elements will move to the right side I think, so you will have to add ltr direction to child elements.

Answer (score 1):

Try `direction:rtl;` in your css.

```
#PARENT_DIV_ID{
    direction:rtl; 
    overflow:auto;
}

#PARENT_DIV_ID div{
    direction:ltr;
}
```

**NOTE:** I just considered inner text is in div.

Answer (score 1):

Use the direction property for the main div (rtl), then for the items use ltr.

```
.career-list {
  height: 300px;
  width: 1000px;
  direction: rtl;
  overflow: auto;
}
.career-list-item{
  ...
  direction: ltr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this will be to use : `jscrollpane`.  See my code below :

**JS  :**

```
$(function()
{
$('.scroll-pane').jScrollPane();
});
```

**CSS :**

```
/* Force the scroll bar to the left hand side of the screen */
.jspVerticalBar
{
    left: 0;
}

.scroll-pane
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Find the **WORKING SOLUTION HERE** : http://jsfiddle.net/hDSnw/1/

I have developed the fiddle based on this [RESOURCE](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/scroll_on_left.html). You can try this one out to see the various stuff you can do with `jscrollpane` .